# How do I get the URL to change via JQuery on an Event?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a Royal Slider event to trigger a url change. The console is displaying "nextpage" as it's supposed to, but the page isn't changing in Chrome or Safari.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a id="next" href="http://google.com">&nbsp;</a>
```

And the JS:

```
    <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


        var slider = $('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider');
        var href = $('#next').attr('href');

        slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function() { 
            console.log("next");
            if(slider.currSlideId === slider.numSlides-1) {
                console.log("nextpage");
                window.location.href = href;
            }
        });

        if(slider.currSlideId === slider.numSlides-1) {
            window.location.href = href;
        }




    });
</script>
```

Comment: U means the page is changing in the other bowsers? Or these are the two browsers you have tried.?

Comment: You want `window.location.assign(href);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the method `widow.location.replace(href);` Full code of JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


        var slider = $('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider');
        var href = $('#next').attr('href');

        slider.ev.on('rsBeforeAnimStart', function() { 
            console.log("next");
            if(slider.currSlideId === slider.numSlides-1) {
                console.log("nextpage");
                window.location.replace(href);
            }
        });

        if(slider.currSlideId === slider.numSlides-1) {
            window.location.replace(href);
        }
```

Here is a link that can help you :http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

*Happy coding!*

Comment: Both assign and replace are hanging up on Safari and Chrome. This seems to be irregular behavior, as it works sometimes, and sometimes not...

Comment: Are you using windows? Because people using windows have had this problem for both chrome and safari. Read more about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/ihU8J4VkM_M)

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a Royal Slider issue, for whatever reason I had to call a different Event (rsBeforeAnimStart instead of rsAfterSlideChange), which works better anyways:

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


        var slider = $('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider');
        var href = $('#next').attr('href');

        slider.ev.on('rsBeforeAnimStart', function() { 
            console.log("next");
            if(slider.currSlideId === slider.numSlides-1) {
                console.log("nextpage");
                window.location.replace(href);
            }
        });

        if(slider.currSlideId === slider.numSlides-1) {
            window.location.replace(href);
        }




    });
</script>
```